# Excel VBA - Read & Output Troubleshooting

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this simple code to move files from Folder "ALL" to "MPD41" with the list as excel spreadsheet. Code will read a list, gets matching files and moves those files to the other folder. I think logically this should work but it doesn't read file & doesn't work. Could you look at this code and point what I did wrong? Thanks!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Move_Files()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim sFromDir As String
    Dim sToDir As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    sFromDir = "C:\Users\Desktop\ALL"
    sToDir = "C:\Users\Desktop\MPD41"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"

    Set rSearch = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    sFile = Dir(sFromDir & "*.xml")

    While sFile > ""
        Set rFound = rSearch.Find(What:=Left(sFile, Len(sFile) - 4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then FSO.CopyFile Source:=sFromDir & sFile, Destination:=sToDir & sFile
        sFile = Dir
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: you a missing a trailing `\ ` from your paths.  As is you are doing `Dir("C:\Users\Desktop\ALL*.xml")`

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't realize this until you look at this! Thank you so much Chris! It works now as good as gold! :)